# Close a child process from a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, process, windows-services

I've written a service in c# that starts different other (child)processes which run in background. How can I close a process in a graceful way? `Process.kill()` is not an option, and `Process.CloseMainWindow()` does not work because the child process has no visible window (and shouldn't have any) .

Tanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO Nathon. Do the child processes written in C# aswell?

Comment: Do the child processes not close themselves once they are done processes?

Comment: Why does the parent process have to close them? A process will close cleanly once it has finished executing. If it hasn't finished executing, I don't believe there is any way to close it 'cleanly'.

Comment: Unless you go down the IPC route and have your parent process signal that a child process should quit, and then have the child process quit gracefully.

Comment: The process is some kind of database to wcf gateway and should run until the user wants to end it. I thought of some build in event that can be called at the child. Like CloseMainWindow()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control that other process you can use WCF to communicate between processes, child process should check and ask service if is time to end process and then child process can do close and do needed cleanup. Here is a clean and simple example

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI to do this(if that is an option). Look at the examples below: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EverythingInWmi02.aspx

Comment: Seems like there is only a TerminateProcess method which is uning kill() for termination.