# Closing process from service without killing the processes

Tags: c++, windows, service

I am searching for a way to close a process running under any user by a windows service running under the system account. I've nearly tried everything but I could not find any solution except killing the process.

**Why can't I kill the process?**
I can't kill the process uses a tray icon. If I kill the process, the tray icon won't disappear.

**What I've tried so far**

I've already tried to use global eventhandles (did not work because the child process got extremely laggy).

I also tried to use PostMessage/SendMessage to communicate with the process. That solution did not work because a windows service can not interact with any user interfaces,...

I found another question (here on stackoverflow) which describes exactly my problem: [Close a child process from a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813184/close-a-child-process-from-a-windows-service). 
This question does not contain a nice solution.

First of all I don't use C++ instead of C#. The next problem is, that the child process uses a mouse hook. So it has so run very fast without many overhead. Otherwise it would get laggy which would mean, that the mouse would lag on the whole system.

So is there really no simple solution to close a process from a windows service?

Comment: The proccess you are trying to kill, do you have control over it? (change the code and rebuild)

Comment: Yes. I can change it to whatever I want. @python

Comment: Global event objects are the obvious solution, and there is absolutely no reason why they would make the child process laggy.  I suspect you implemented this solution improperly.

Answer (score 0):

A service can use [`SetProcessWindowStation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetThreadDesktop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to attach to the interactive desktop of the target process before then sending messages to the target process.

Alternatively, the service can use [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to run a new process in the same session as the target process, and then that process can send messages to the target process.

Comment: I've just tried it out. SetProcessWindowStation does not work. I am going to try out SetThreadDesktop now but I am afraid of that this also won't work.

Comment: Well. Now I've also tried `SetThreadDesktop`. Both did not work. I just do not get access to any user interfaces.

The problem is the as already mentioned "session 0 isolation". I have to start a process in a different session.

Comment: I've ended up in using the solution described here (see ApplicationLoader::StartProcessAndBypassUAC): http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=35773&zep=ApplicationLoaderService%2fApplicationLoader.cs&rzp=%2fKB%2fvista-security%2fSubvertingVistaUAC%2f%2fBypassVistaUAC.zip

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `SetProcessWindowStation` and `SetThreadDesktop` are restricted to window stations and desktops within the remote desktop session associated with the process, so as of Windows Vista they won't help services trying to interact with the end user or with end user processes.